# How Can I get My C program to run something when a certain key is pressed (X11)

Tags: x11

I have a C Program, which currently gets the state of CapsLock, NumLock, etc.

However, I would like it to run in the background and wait for a certain keypress / release ( be it CapsLock or NumLock ) then run a function.
How can I do this?

Comment: Look up ncurses: https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ ... It can do exactly what you want.

Comment: "which currently gets the state of CapsLock" how?